# PyAutoGUI python 3.6 модули

Tags: python, sublime-text, python-3.6, pyautogui

У меня Python версии 3.6. Я использую Sublime Text и PyCharm. Пытаюсь разобрать с модулем PyAutoGUI. Когда я импортирую его в Sublime Text - выдает ошибку:

> File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\AAA\Hello.py", line 1, in
>
> import pyautogui
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'

Но когда я имортирую его в PyCharm - все работает.

Как решить проблему?

Comment: Когда вы вызываете импорт в pycharm тот вызывает интерпретатор питона, что в текущем проекте (вообще, в консоли запуска видно откуда запускается питон) и если у вас при этом не ругается, значит у того питона есть тот модуль pyautogui. Соответственно, у питона, запускаемого Сублайм нет модуля pyautogui. Вообще, мне плохо представляется зачем заводить сублайм, если есть pycharm :)

Comment: А так можно как-то сделать чтобы pyautogui работал в консоли? Я забыл дописать что если в консоли вписать "pip install pyautogui" он напишет что он уже установлен.

Comment: В консоли sublime? -- Не знаю. А так посмотрите для sublime файл конфига плагина, в нем можно указать нужный вам питон (а конкретно тот, что через pycharm у вас работает): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536094/setting-python-path-for-sublimerepl-from-sublime-text

Comment: ```pip3 install pyautogui``` Pip3!:)